# Array of Objects are twice after return

Tags: powershell, arraylist, powershell-3.0

I have a Simple code.
My problem is why the Array have the double Number of elements after return it.

```
function Create_obj {
    return [pscustomobject] @{
        'Tag1' = [STRING]''
        'Tag2' = [STRING]''
    }
}

function Get-Obj_Array {
    $arr_obj=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $i=1
    for(; $i -le 10; $i++) {
        $tmp_obj = Create_obj
        $arr_obj.Add($tmp_obj)
        $arr_obj[$i-1].Tag1 = $i
        $arr_obj[$i-1].Tag2 = 'Num' + $i
    }
    Write-Host $arr_obj.count
    return $arr_obj
}

$Erg = Get-Obj_Array
$Erg.Count

$Erg | Format-Table
```

Do you know why?

I try to Create an Array of custom objects.

Comment: `$null = $arr_obj.Add($tmp_obj)` or use a `List<T>`